# What web UI framework is VS Code built using?

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-framework

I want to build an app like Visual Studio Code. I know it's built using electron, but I don't know what web framework they have used with electron.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I have seen the code. Can you tell me how could I run it?

Comment: The documentation has a topic called "How to build and run from source" which sounds like it might be relevant

Answer (score 3):

None. Quoting Erich Gamma from [What frontend framework does VS Code use?](https://youtu.be/gnKzJRr-rd0?t=26),

> What many people don't know is that we decided to not use any UI frameworks from the beginning, and that's still true today because performance is very important to us, and we want to be to be fully in control of our own destiny right? So we don't want to chase a framework or track some performance from in the framework. We want to be directly as close to the DOM as possible.

That also applies to [Monaco](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor)- the editor component of VS Code.